# monitoring network pcs

Tags: networking

I am well aware that employers monitor content and activity of their employees; I was just wondering though if its possible to know when someone has remotely connected to your pc or is monitoring your pc virtually. I tried looking at the task manager but its hard to determine which process this is and of course it does not have to be in task manager either. I am not concerned about my activities since I realize everything is logged anyway and I don't even check my personal email at work anyway, but its just interesting to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using windows and that command prompt is not disabled I believe [netstat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstat) is what you are looking for. It allows you to view incoming and outgoing connections, from there it shouldn't be too hard to figure out which one is your local workplace proxy. Of course, this requires you to keep checking at intervals and it does involve a CLI which you may not be comfortable with. Therefore, an alternative would be [Moo0 connection watcher](http://www.moo0.com/?top=http://www.moo0.com/software/ConnectionWatcher/). Also, in regard to finding the process that is monitoring your machine, the application should be located in the panel on the bottom right of your screen unless it is hidden- I believe that VNC is quite common.